# Subject GRE exam 9768 Q.12

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, gre-exam

The question is in the given picture :

[image]

And the answer is C as shown in the answer sheet below:

[image]

But this answer is so strange for me as I know that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points and so the choice (A) is true also.

Could anyone explain this for me please? I want why should I exclude every choice other than (C).

Comment: (A) is not true. What is true is that $B$ is *not* closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question states that $b$ is **not** in $B$. Since $b$ is a limit point of $B$, $B$ does **not** contain all its limits points. So $B$ is not closed.

EDIT:

If there is an open interval $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ with no element of $B$, then $b-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $B$, which is a contradiction. So every open interval around $b$ intersects $B$, that is, $b$ is a limit point of $B$. This proves that C is true.

$B$ is not closed, because $b$ is a limit point of $B$ but $b\notin B$. So A is false.

Under the hypotesis of the question, $B$ may or may not be open. For example, $(b-1,b)$ is open, $b$ is its least upper bound and $b\notin (b-1,b)$. So, although we can not say that B is false, we can not either say that it is true. So B is not the correct answer.

D is false. We can define $b_n$ to be in the intersection $(b-\frac1n,b)\cap B$ to build a sequence in $B$ that converges to $b$.

E is also false, as we have already seen.

Comment: could u exclude each choice other than (C) for me please by saying your evidence.

Comment: why b is a limit point of B may be B is a discrete set not an interval like {1,2,3} for example.

Comment: A discrete set contains it's least upper bound whenever they have them, so those examples are excluded.

Comment: a discrete set contains its minimum but does not contain its supremum, this is my understanding.@Bernard8

Comment: So detailed and clear answer thank u so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's think of a tangible example.

Let $B = (0,1)$, and $b = 1$.

A. Is $B$ closed?  Evidently not.

B. Is $B$ not open? In this case no.
I could have written that $B' = [0,1)$ though, which is not open.  Either case, this doesn't *have* to be true.

C. Is $b$ a limit point of $B$? It has to be, otherwise it wouldn't be the least upper bound.

D. This isn't true - for our example, consider $b_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$.
This is in $B$, and converges to $b$.

E. This isn't true.  We'd want an interval of the form $(1,2)$ or something like that, but $b$ isn't in this.
If we try $(x,2)$ for $x<1$, $b$ will be in this, but it will always share another element of $B$.

For questions like (multiple choice), thinking of tangible examples can help a ton.

Comment: It is not clear for me how is $B' = [0,1)$, could u clarify please?

Comment: By $B'$ I just meant some other set.  The example $B$ isn't "not open", but not _every_ such set $B$ is open.  As an example, $[0,1)$ is a similar set, but _is_ not open.

Comment: Thank u so much for your detailed and clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=(0,1)$ and $b=1$. Then all choices except for $C$ are false.